# Android Espresso: checking for a checked checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, junit4, android-espresso

I am new to Espresso at this point and I am getting this Exception:

> android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id:
>   android:id/checkbox' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.

This happens when trying to check for a non checked box:  `onView(withId(android.R.id.checkbox)).check(matches(not(isChecked())));`

My understanding is that I have 3 checkboxes and for some reason they all match this description, my question becomes: how can I differentiate between the checkboxes?

This is the error log that I am getting:

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id: android:id/checkbox' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2560, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2392, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909225, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2308, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=84.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->ActionBarOverlayLayout{id=2131492999, res-name=decor_content_parent, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2308, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2112, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=196.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->ScrollView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2112, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------>LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=1162, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=5}
|
+------->FontedTextView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1334, height=88, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=53.0, y=105.0, text=Paperless Delivery & Data Sharing, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------->FontedTextView{id=-1, desc=Check/un-check each box to change your preferences then tap save., visibility=VISIBLE, width=1334, height=138, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=53.0, y=263.0, text=Check/un-check each box to change your preferences then tap save., input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------->View{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=1, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=471.0}
|
+------->LinearLayout{id=2131493744, res-name=settings_prefs_consents_layout, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=689, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=472.0, child-count=3}
|
+-------->LinearLayout{id=2131493745, res-name=meh, desc=Entitlement 1 checked. Description 1. Read more., visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=191, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=32.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckBox{id=16908289, res-name=checkbox, visibility=VISIBLE, width=103, height=102, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=53.0, y=53.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=true, has-links=false, is-checked=true} ****MATCHES****
|
+--------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1196, height=138, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=191.0, y=53.0, child-count=2}
|
+---------->FontedTextView{id=16908308, res-name=text1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1196, height=69, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Entitlement 1, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---------->FontedTextView{id=16908309, res-name=text2, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1196, height=69, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=69.0, text=Description 1 Read more., input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+-------->LinearLayout{id=2131493745, res-name=meh, desc=Entitlement 2 unchecked. Description 2. Read more., visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=191, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=223.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckBox{id=16908289, res-name=checkbox, visibility=VISIBLE, width=102, height=102, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=53.0, y=53.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false} ****MATCHES****
|
+--------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1197, height=138, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=190.0, y=53.0, child-count=2}
|
+---------->FontedTextView{id=16908308, res-name=text1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1197, height=69, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Entitlement 2, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---------->FontedTextView{id=16908309, res-name=text2, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1197, height=69, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=69.0, text=Description 2 Read more., input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+-------->LinearLayout{id=2131493745, res-name=meh, desc=Entitlement 3 checked. Description 3. Read more., visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=191, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=414.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckBox{id=16908289, res-name=checkbox, visibility=VISIBLE, width=103, height=102, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=53.0, y=53.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=true} ****MATCHES****
|
+--------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1196, height=138, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=191.0, y=53.0, child-count=2}
|
+---------->FontedTextView{id=16908308, res-name=text1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1196, height=69, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Entitlement 3, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Espresso, but doing a search, I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoStartGuide#Finding_a_view_with_onView) on their wiki:

> Sometimes, R.id values are shared between multiple views. When this happens an attempt to use a particular R.id. gives you an AmbiguousViewMatcherException (for example). The exception message provides you with a text representation of the current view hierarchy, which you can search for and find the views that match the non-unique R.id:
>
> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException:
> This matcher matches multiple views in the hierarchy: (withId: is <123456789>)
> ...
>
> +-----SomeView{id=123456789, res-name=plus_one_standard_ann_button, visibility=VISIBLE, width=523, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, window-focus=true,
> is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, enabled=true, selected=false, is-layout-requested=false, text=, root-is-layout-requested=false, x=0.0, y=625.0, child-count=1}
> ****MATCHES****
> |
> +------>OtherView{id=123456789, res-name=plus_one_standard_ann_button, visibility=VISIBLE, width=523, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, window-focus=true,
> is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, enabled=true, selected=false, is-layout-requested=false, text=Hello!, root-is-layout-requested=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
> ****MATCHES****
> ```
>
> Looking through the various attributes of the views, you may find uniquely identifiable properties (in the example above, one of the views has the text "Hello!"). You can use this to narrow down your search by using combination matchers:
>
> ```
> onView(allOf(withId(R.id.my_view), withText("Hello!")))
> ```
>
> You can also use not to reverse any of the matchers:
>
> ```
> onView(allOf(withId(R.id.my_view), not(withText("Unwanted"))))
> ```
>
> See ViewMatchers for the view matchers provided by Espresso.

So, you should either:

- Use the filters above
- Assign unique IDs. It is easier in the long run, esp. before your code becomes far too complex to change it.

Answer (score 1):

In your layout xml file, you can define for every view three useful test matchers:

- `android:id` - it's well-know ID of your view (every view should have an its ID, it's really good design pattern)
- `android:text` - text to be displayed on some views like `Button` or `TextView`
- `android:contentDescription` - like ID, every view may have its content description.

Using at least one of these elements cause, that you can use:

- `onView(withId(R.id.help))...` - if your view has an ID
- `onView(withText(R.string.help_desc))...` - if your view has a text
- `onView(withContentDescription("Help"))...` - if your view has a content description.

Your `CheckBox` views don't have any of these `matchers`. Please, fix it.

Comment: Not a solution for the following scenario: You have a Linear Layout that you fill programmatically with a number of identical child views. Perhaps you don't have text to match with inside this view. Perhaps the text is randomly generated and not possible to hardcode a matching string.

Answer (score 0):

The new Espresso test recorder in Android Studio does a great job of fully qualifying your queries by checking the class type, the parent, adding a custom matcher, etc.  It's a great training aid for learning best practices.

Here is an example of machine generated Espresso code from the AS test recorder.  Combining "allOf" and "withParent" is quite powerful for resolving AmbiguousViewMatcherExceptions.

```
    ViewInteraction imageButton3 = onView(
        allOf(withContentDescription("Navigate up"),
            withParent(allOf(withId(R.id.action_bar),
                withParent(withId(R.id.action_bar_container)))),
            isDisplayed()));
    imageButton3.perform(click());
```